# How do I create a table best suited for storing address information

Tags: oracle, index, partitioning

I have to create an address table in Oracle. Table is expected to hold millions of row. I created a table looking like this

```
 Table Address
    ID | Address Line1 | Address Line2 | Address Line3| City | Zip | ..|
```

The queries that I expect from my client may contain AddressLine1 and Zip or AddressLine1, Zip and City in which case the above table structure would not the most ideal. I don't want to have to scan the entire table for every query. I know for sure that the client queries will at least contain zip or city, am thinking that I have to create and indices on Zip and City. Should I consider anything else in my design?

I considered partitioning the table, but am going to start with a blank database and rows get added over a period of time, am not sure if I can dynamically create those partitions based on City or zip.

Also my expectations is that the database has to be optimized for reads more than writes

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would analyze the data and seriously consider scalability.

-Do you need to retain an old address for prior billing?
-Do you need to know when a client changed addresses?
-Are other countries currently involved now?
-Will other countries be involved?

3 address lines may not be enough.

You will likely need a total of:

-5 address lines
-City
-State
-Zip
-country
-Province ?
-CreateDate
-Expiredate
-Region  (I would consider this a way to group Zip codes 90000 series is Southern California, etc).  You could adjust later as needed.
-AcctType (billing, sales mailings, main office)

Comment: Let me explain this even further, we have a addressing service, which given a address gives out formatted address. For example if you make a request for 123, Main Ave, Highland Parkway, Carolina 27559, my service would run through some business logic return 123 Main Avenue, Highland Pky, North Carolina 27559, USA. I would also like to store this request and response, so that I dont have to go through the business logic again, the next time the same requests comes in. So the request fields and the response fields are fixed, they are not going to change

Comment: If you don't need any additional fields, then I would consider partitioning by zip code ranges.  0-10000, 10001-20000, etc.